# My Custom ListView display nothing

Tags: java, android, listview

I am newbie in android. I want to create a custom listview arrayadapter. I have followed some tutorial but my emulator shows nothing for the Custom ListView. Can anyone help me figure out where is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Here is my custom_listview_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customListView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my custom_listview_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="64dp">

     <!-- <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clv_imageView"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/> -->

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/clv_textView2"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/tv_definition"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/clv_textView"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/tv_word"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my MyPerformanceArrayAdapter.java

```
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyPerformanceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DefinitionObject>{
    private List<DefinitionObject> entries;
    private Activity activity;

    public MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId,         List<DefinitionObject> entries) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
    this.entries = entries;
    this.activity = a;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView item1;
    public TextView item2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clv_textView);
        holder.item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clv_textView2);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    final DefinitionObject custom = entries.get(position);
    if (custom != null) {
        holder.item1.setText(custom.getWord());
        holder.item2.setText(custom.getFav());
    }
    return v;
    }

    }
```

and lastly, this is my Activity named TempCLV.java

```
    package com.example.myidictionary;

    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class TempCLV extends Activity {

private MySQLiteDefinitionHelper db;
String tblName = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_listview_main);

    Intent msjIntent = getIntent();
    tblName = msjIntent.getStringExtra(WordDefinitionHomeActivity.TABLENAME2);

    }

    public void refresh()
    {
    db = new MySQLiteDefinitionHelper(this);
    final List<DefinitionObject> values = db.getAllWords(tblName);

    ListView mylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.customListView);
    MyPerformanceArrayAdapter adapter = new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(this, R.id.customListView, values);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure values contains something ?

Comment: @blackbelt refresh is where he sets adapter i don't see it being called any where and you may be right about values containing some data

Comment: `refresh` is not called..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `refresh` in `onCreate` since you are setting the adapter to list view there.

Make sure your `values` has some data

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.custom_listview_main);
Intent msjIntent = getIntent();
tblName = msjIntent.getStringExtra(WordDefinitionHomeActivity.TABLENAME2);
refresh();
}
```

Also you can move the inflater initialization to the constructor of adapter class. No need to initialize in `getView`

```
LayoutInflater vi; 
public MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId,List<DefinitionObject> entries) {
super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
this.entries = entries;
vi =(LayoutInflater)a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
}
```

Comment: thank you sir. I forgot and didn't realize at all for the function that does not been called. -__-"

Answer (score 0):

Please call refresh method at least for first time to set the the adapter in your MainActivity' `onCreate` method..